# how do I change a socket connection to just timeout vs. being completely down?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, amazon-ec2, redis

I have a bug where a long running process works fine for the first few days, but then a query to redis reaches the 45 second timeout I have set.  That is, if redis was totally down my program would just crash, but it doesn't.  It waits and waits (45 seconds) timesout and tries again for another 45 seconds over and over.

If I stop the process and re-start it, everything is fine again for another few days.

This is running on ec2 with Elastic Load Balancing with my process on a different box than redis.

I need to re-create this situation on my local development environment.  How can I not kill my local redis, but rather put it into a state where reads will timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe turn off the port? This might be interpreted as connections refused/down.

Perhaps put another non-redis app on said port and just have it not respond. In other words, accept incoming connections but don't respond. You could probably write a simple app that accepts TCP connections and then does nothing in the language of your choice, and have it start on the Redis port in order to test this situation.